# Fetch image from URL with kanji

Tags: java, url, character-encoding, internationalization

I want to fetch an image from a remote URL.

```
String url =  "http://見.香港/images/wonton.jpg";
String url2 = IDN.toUnicode(url);
BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new URL(url2));
System.out.println(bi);
```

This code always fails with

> javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't get input stream from URL!
>   Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: 見.香港

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only encode the host portion of the URL and make sure you are using `IDN.toASCII()` rather than `IDN.toUnicode()`

```
String fullUrl = "http://見.香港/images/wonton.jpg";
URL url = new URL(fullUrl);

url.getProtocol(); // "http"
url.getHost(); // "見.香港"
url.getPath(); // "/images/wonton.jpg"

String asciiHost = IDN.toASCII(url.getHost());
String validUrl = url.getProtocol() + "://" + asciiHost + url.getPath();
System.out.println(validUrl);
BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new URL(validUrl));
```

Console Output:
http://xn--nw2a.xn--j6w193g/images/wonton.jpg

Note that you might need to URLEncode the resource portion of the URI if it were to contain characters such as spaces.

Comment: Thank you Jon, that was just what I needed.